# Trying to get the state value after immediate state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have declared a variable with `usestate` like as below

```
const [currentStepNumber, setCurrentStepNumber] = useState(0);
```

and then I am updating the state when I click on move function like as below

```
const handleMove = () => {
   setCurrentStepNumber(currentStepNumber + 1);
   const { label } = Object.values(PROJECT_PHASE).find(s => s.stepNumber === currentStepNumber);
   const projectPhaseID = projectPhaseData.projectPhases.find(a => a.name === label).id;
   console.log(currentStepNumber);
   // need to do API call as well in move function 
};
```

And the `currentStepNumber` still shows `0` instead of `1` only and i cannot use a timer to trigger and update the values. Is there any other approach to achieve this?

I need to update the `currentStepNumber` only in move function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: No it won't i have to other operations as well after updating the state

Comment: Doesn't matter; setting state is async; that's React 101 (also: the stupid "Does this answer your question?" is auto-inserted by SO when you mark as dupe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: @DrewReese That's the one, thanks

Comment: @ChrisG I've BM'd it since this question is asked almost daily. ;)  Though, the underlying reason is exactly the same... react component lifecycle and reconciliation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be able to try `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const postStepData = async () => {
     try {
         // call the api
         const response = await postDataPromise({...data, currentStepNumber});
         setCurrentStepNumber(0);
         setSomeOtherState(false);
     } catch (e) {
         console.log(e)
     }
   }

   const { label } = Object.values(PROJECT_PHASE).find(s => s.stepNumber === currentStepNumber);
   const projectPhaseID = projectPhaseData.projectPhases.find(a => a.name === label).id;
   console.log(currentStepNumber);
   /*
    * as an example only call api on step 4
   */
   if (currentStepNumber === 4) {
      void postStepData();
   }
}, [currentStepNumber])

const handleMove = () => setCurrentStepNumber(currentStepNumber + 1);
```

reference:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: thanks for response !! , i need to have api call as well followed by getting that projectPhaseId in the same move function.. With your code can i do that

Comment: Hmm i need to call the api in the current step it self cannot wait until step 4

Comment: @EnigmaState can remove the `if` statement, and just run the api call on each state update?, or handle the cases where it should be called?

Comment: do you mean the useEffect should run if there is any update to currentStepNumber right

Comment: @EnigmaState yep

Comment: any condition need to check inside useEffect before running api call just to watch the current stepnumber or not needed

Comment: @EnigmaState `currentStepNumber` is passed into the dependency array so the example useEffect will only run when `currentStepNumber` is updated. `useEffect(() => {...}, [currentStepNumber])`. If I understand your question, useEffect watches the current step number, and will run if it is updated, so no extra watching of step number is required for useEffect to get called.

Comment: thanks.. i need to run this complete useEffect when only the currentstepnumber changes and if don't include other dependencies i am getting warnings as well.. how can i avoid those warnings React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies:  `projectPhaseData`. Either include them or remove the dependency array `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217922/discussion-between-enigma-state-and-jmunsch).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new `currentStepNumber` in [React's `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [currentStepNumber, setCurrentStepNumber] = useState(0);
  
  const handleMove = () => {
    setCurrentStepNumber(currentStepNumber + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const { label } = Object.values(PROJECT_PHASE).find(s => s.stepNumber === currentStepNumber);
    const projectPhaseID = projectPhaseData.projectPhases.find(a => a.name === label).id;
    console.log(currentStepNumber);
  }, [currentStepNumber])

  return (
    <>{/* some jsx */}</>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i have to do api call as well once i get the correct projectPhaseId in move function itself..